# Domain Name on linux server

Tags: linux, webserver, virtual-machine

I have a virtual Linux server running with some web pages stored, I was wandering rather than using the ip address, would it be possible to attach a domain name to it temporarally. for example www.myWebSite.com

Comment: use /etc/hosts The format is pretty clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `/etc/hosts` The format is pretty clear.